# How to put where condition in select condition in Linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, dataset

[image: After adding Mickaël Derriey's code. I am getting compile error. Can you tell me what's wrong. ?]I have an issue. Here i want to filter based on some condition for **Fields** and **Datafield**. How can i do that?

Below is my linq query:
  **Note:** This piece of code is working.

```
 DataSet queries = query.GetQueryDetails(reportName);
 str = queries.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new Query { CommandText = dataRow.Field<string>("CommandText"), DataSetName = dataRow.Field<string>("DataSetName"), Key = dataRow.Field<int>("Fields"), Value=dataRow.Field<string>("DataField") }).ToList();
```

And i want to do something like this, but it's not possible.:
**Note:** Below code is not working. showing compile error.

```
 DataSet queries = query.GetQueryDetails(reportName);
 str = queries.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new Query { CommandText = dataRow.Field<string>("CommandText"), DataSetName = dataRow.Field<string>("DataSetName"), Key = dataRow.Field<int>("Fields").Where(dataRow.Field<int>(("DictVal") == "Key")), Value=dataRow.Field<string>("DataField").Where(dataRow.Field<string>(("DictVal") == "Value")) }).ToList();
```

I know we cannot put where condition wherever we want. But i want to select **Fields** and **DataField** columns based on condition.
Can anyone please help me? Is it possible?

**Just for reference:**

```
public partial class Query
{
    public string DataSetName { get; set; }
    public string CommandText { get; set; }
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Note:** CommandText, DataSetName, Fields and DictVal are the columns of the table.

Comment: I know its not possible to put where condition like that or inside select condition. But i am open to any kind of suggestions or help.

Comment: The code that's working is exactly the same as the code that's **not** working, did you make a mistake in copy & paste?

Comment: Sorry! Can you please check now?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something like:

```cs
str = queries
    .Tables[1]
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(dataRow =>
    {
        var query = new Query
        {
            CommandText = dataRow.Field<string>("CommandText"),
            DataSetName = dataRow.Field<string>("DataSetName")
        };
        
        switch (dataRow.Field<string>("DictVal"))
        {
            case "Key":
                query.Key = dataRow.Field<int>("Fields");
                break;

            case "Value":
                query.Value = dataRow.Field<string>("DataField");
                break;
        }

        return query;
    })
    .ToList();
```

This uses the other notation for lamda expressions where they declare a full body.

Comment: I will be editing my post by adding compile error screenshot of your code. Please have a look

Comment: It seems a variable or parameter named query is already defined in your code. Can you try changing it in the code I posted to use another variable name?

Answer (score 1):

What compile error did you get?

Following is my answer:

```
str = queries.Tables[1]
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(dataRow =>
    {
        var dictVal = dataRow.Field<string>("DictVal");
        return new Query
        {
            CommandText = dataRow.Field<string>("CommandText"), 
            DataSetName = dataRow.Field<string>("DataSetName"),
            Key = dictVal == "Key" 
                ? dataRow.Field<int>("Fields")
                : int.MinValue, 
            Value = dictVal == "Value"
                ? dataRow.Field<string>("DataField") 
                : string.Empty
        };
    });
```